# PERCENTILE_CONT() returns same value regardless of input parameter

Tags: sql, singlestore

I would like to get the 5th, 50th, 95th percentile of a table

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, AVG(col4), STD(col4), 
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.05) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col4) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3) as 5th_percentile, 
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col4)  
        OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3) as 50th_percentile, 
    PERCENTILE_CONT(0.95) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col4)  
        OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3) as 95th_percentile
FROM table
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
LIMIT 100
```

What I end up getting back is 5th_percentile == 50th_percentile == 95th_percentile

```
AVG(col4)   STD(col4)   5th_percentile   50th_percentile  95th_percentile
300.000000  0.000000    300.000000       300.000000       300.000000
67.076600   16.968851   82.031792        82.031792        82.031792
66.166136   11.452172   78.348846        78.348846        78.348846
544.262809  68.269014   605.797302       605.797302       605.797302
22.523138   1.820358    24.000000        24.000000        24.000000
```

Whats going on?

Edit: The db is MemSQL

Comment: Which dbms?????  `SQL` is just a language used by many vendors!!

Comment: It uses memsql which I believe has similar syntax as MySQL

Comment: Then add the tag to your question.  You don't want anything give you a solution, but you can't use it because it's for the wrong dbms.

Comment: just did! I haven't seen too many memsql solutions on stackoverflow though, so I didn't want to deter anyone who wasn't familiar from answering what they would do on their dbms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT col1, col2, col3, 
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.05) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col4) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3) as 5th_percentile,
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col4) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3) as 50th_percentile,
        PERCENTILE_CONT(0.95) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col4) 
            OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3) as 95th_percentile
FROM table
)
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3, 5th_percentile, 50th_percentile, 95th_percentile
FROM a
LIMIT 100
```

This works, looks like you can't do a groupby with percentile_cont

Answer (score 3):

Window functions operate *after* the GROUP BY clause. The GROUP BY produces one row per group, which is why the PERCENTILE_CONT window functions all return the same value.

You want to compute the window functions first, then GROUP BY afterwards. You can do this by putting the window functions in an inner subselect, and the GROUP BY in an outer select.

Here is documentation from postgres which explains how window functions relate to group by (this is standard ANSI SQL, and MemSQL does the same thing):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

> The rows considered by a window function are those of the "virtual table" produced by the query's FROM clause as filtered by its WHERE, GROUP BY, and HAVING clauses if any. For example, a row removed because it does not meet the WHERE condition is not seen by any window function. A query can contain multiple window functions that slice up the data in different ways by means of different OVER clauses, but they all act on the same collection of rows defined by this virtual table.

Note that in MemSQL, if you use a column that isn't grouped or aggregated, such as col4 in your query, you get an arbitrary value out of the rows in the group, i.e. it behaves like an ANY_VALUE aggregate. In a future version of MemSQL, this query will instead return an error, to help you avoid writing queries with unintended behavior like this.

Answer (score 1):

`PERCENTILE_CONT()` -- at least in some databases -- can be either an aggregation function or a window function.

What I think is happening is that the value is being calculated *after* the aggregation -- I'm not sure why.  To be honest, I would expect the code to get a syntax error, because `col4` is not aggregated.  In other words `(ORDER BY MAX(col4))` should work, but not `(ORDER BY col4)` because the percentile is calculated *after* the aggregation.

But try without the `OVER` clause:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, AVG(col4), STD(col4), 
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.05) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col4)  as 5th_percentile, 
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col4) as 50th_percentile, 
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.95) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col4) as 95th_percentile
FROM table
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
LIMIT 100;
```

EDIT:

Your database doesn't seem to support `PERCENTILE_CONT()` as an aggregation function.  No accounting for taste.  Most do.

The workaround is `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3,
       AVG(col4) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3),
       STD(col4) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3),
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.05) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col4) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3)  as 5th_percentile, 
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col4) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3) as 50th_percentile, 
       PERCENTILE_CONT(0.95) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY col4) OVER (PARTITION BY col1, col2, col3) as 95th_percentile
FROM table
LIMIT 100;
```

Or using a subquery.

Comment: I can't take away the OVER() statement, but when I take away the paramaters of OVER() statement, it applies the percentile rank without grouping. Although, it does return different values for the 5th, 50th, and 95th percentiles, which I suppose is a step in the right direction.

Edit: For clarity, when I take away the paramaters for the OVER() statement, different values for col1, col2, col3 all have the exact same 5th, 50th, and 95th percentile values, whereas before each group of col1, col2, col3 would have different values - which is the desired outcome